# Returning LINQ to Entities Query Result as JSON string

Tags: linq, json, linq-to-entities

I'm attempting to construct a web service that allows for RESTful requests to return LINQ to Entities data as JSON string data.  I have no problem executing a call to the database that returns one specific object:

```
public Product GetTicket(string s)
        {
            int id = Convert.ToInt32(s);


MWAEntities context = new MWAEntities();
        var ticketEntity = (from p
                            in context.HD_TicketCurrentStatus
                            where p.Ticket_ID == id
                            select p).FirstOrDefault();
        if (ticketEntity != null)
            return TranslateTicketEntityToTicket(ticketEntity);
        else
            throw new Exception("Invalid Ticket ID");

        /**
        Product product = new Product();
        product.TicketId = 1;
        product.TicketDescription = "MyTest";
        product.TicketOperator = "Chad Cross";
        product.TicketStatus = "Work in Progress";
        return product;
        */
    }
    private Product TranslateTicketEntityToTicket(
        HD_TicketCurrentStatus ticketEntity)
    {
        Product ticket = new Product();
        ticket.TicketId = ticketEntity.Ticket_ID;
        ticket.TicketDescription = ticketEntity.F_PrivateMessage;
        ticket.TicketStatus = ticketEntity.L_Status;
        ticket.TicketOperator = ticketEntity.L_Technician;
        return ticket;
    }
```

Using curl, I get json data:

```
curl http://192.168.210.129:1111/ProductService/ticket/2
{"TicketDescription":"Firewall seems to be blocking her connection to www.rskco.com","TicketId":2,"TicketOperator":"Jeff","TicketStatus":"Completed"}
```

That being said, I have no idea how to get a string of JSON objects using the following query:

```
public List<MyTicket> GetMyTickets(string userId)
    {
        MWAEntities context = new MWAEntities();

        /**
         * List of statuses that I consider to be "open"
         * */
        string[] statusOpen = new string[] { "Work in Progress", "Assigned", "Unassigned" };

        /**
         * List of tickets with my userID
         * */
        var tickets = (from p
                       in context.HD_TicketCurrentStatus
                       where statusOpen.Contains(p.L_Status) & p.L_Technician == userId
                       select new MyTicket(p.Ticket_ID, p.Ticket_CrtdUser, p.F_PrivateMessage, p.Ticket_CrtdDate, p.L_Status));

        return ???;
    }
```

MyTicket is a type defined as follows:

```
[DataContract]
public class MyTicket
{
    public MyTicket(int ticketId, string TicketCreator, string FirstPrivateMessage, DateTime TicketCreatedDate, string Status)
    {
        this.TicketId = ticketId;
        this.TicketCreator = TicketCreator;
        this.FirstPrivateMessage = FirstPrivateMessage;
        this.TicketCreatedDate = TicketCreatedDate;
        this.Status = Status;
    }
    [DataMember]
    public int TicketId { get; set; }       

    [DataMember]
    public string TicketCreator { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string FirstPrivateMessage { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public DateTime TicketCreatedDate { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Status { get; set; }

    //p.Ticket_CrtdUser, p.Ticket_CrtdDate, p.Ticket_ID, p.F_PrivateMessage
}
```

I would just like to get a list of JSON strings as output in order to parse using JS.  I've tried using a foreach loop to parse "var" into a List of MyTicket objects, calling .ToList()), etc., to no avail.

I cannot change the backend (SQL 2005/2008), but I'm trying to use a standard HTML/JS client to consume a .NET 4.0 web service.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I've spent literally days searching and reading books (especially on O'Reilly's Safari site) and I have not found a reasonable solution :(.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted to add that I eventually got help to solve this.  I'm not using business entities even though I'm using the Entity Framework.  This may not be a wise decision, but I'm increasingly confused with Linq2SQL and Linq2EF.  Here is the the code that made the above work:

```
public List<MyTicket> GetMyTickets(string userId)
    {
        MWAEntities context = new MWAEntities();

        /**
         * List of statuses that I consider to be "open"
         * */
        string[] statusOpen = new string[] { "Work in Progress", "Created"};

        var tickets = (from p
                       in context.HD_TicketCurrentStatus
                       where statusOpen.Contains(p.L_Status) & p.L_Technician == userId
                       select new MyTicket{
                           TicketId = p.Ticket_ID,
                           TicketCreatedDate = p.Ticket_CrtdDate,
                           FirstPrivateMessage = p.F_PrivateMessage,
                           Status = p.L_Status,
                           TicketCreator = p.Ticket_CrtdUser
                       });
        return tickets.ToList();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

use Json.NET: http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
serializer.Serialize(Response.Output, tickets); // per your example
```

EDIT: Argh, the above is if you want to handle the serialization yourself.

In your example, change the return of the method from List to Ticket[] and do

```
return tickets.ToArray();
```

Comment: Unfortunately changing the return type results in what I've gotten in almost all of my iterations: a runtime error:

"Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities"

I've seen this noted in several blogs as a severe limitation of L2E but I'm really not sure what other layer I can use to accomplish my goal: constructing a web service to interface with a SQL 2005/2008 backend to be consumed by a RESTful JS/HTML client.

Comment: You can always just return a string with the json, in which case my original answer will work for you.  Your other alternative to likely the better practice.  Don't push your Entities over the wire.  If you're exposing the entities that map to the DB over your service, then you're tightly coupling your service to your database.  If your db model changes, all of your clients will break.  Make a POCO layer, translate the db objects to the service object and then you'll solve both problems (the L2E error and the tightly coupling architecture).  More work and more code, but better long term.

Comment: Thanks Sean.  More research it is.  I want to do it the right way not just the way that may work.